# Why is the ADM-mass well-defined?

Tags: dg.differential-geometry

I have some questions concerning the definition of the ADM-mass of an asymptotically flat $3$-manifold: An Riemannian $3$-manifold is said to be asymptotically flat, if there exists a compact set $K \subset M$ and a diffeomorphism of $M \setminus K$ with the set of all $x \in \mathbb{R}^3$ fulfilling  $\mid x \mid >1$ such that the components $g_{ij}$ of the metric under this diffeomorphism fulfill the estimates $\mid g_{ij}-\delta_{ij} \mid \leq C \mid x \mid^{-1}$, $\mid \partial_{k}g_{ij} \mid \leq C \mid x \mid^{-2}$, $\mid \partial_{k}\partial_{l}g_{ij} \mid \leq C \mid x \mid^{-3}$.
The ADM-mass of an asymptotically flat Riemannian $3$-manifold $(M, g)$ is then given by the expression
$$m_{ADM}(M)= \lim_{r \rightarrow \infty} \frac{1}{16 \pi} \int_{\{\mid x \mid =r\}} \sum_{i, j=1} (\partial_j g_{ij}-\partial_i g_{jj})\frac{x^i}{r}$$
My question now is: Why is the value $m_{ADM}(M)$ well-defined, i.e. why does the limit and integral exist and why is the value independent of the choice of $K$ and the diffeomorphism?
Every help will be appreciated.

Comment: see R. Bartnik, The mass of an asymptotically flat manifold, CPAM 1986